# How to get the start and last index of a string match

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the last and first index of a string match. For example:

```
var text = 'I am a string and this is an image <img src="image.jpeg">';
```

What I would like to do is get the first index and last index of the match. example I have attempted:

```
<script>
        function getLightBox(text) {
                var result = str.match(/<img src="(.*?)>/g).map(function(val){
                var res = val.replace(/<\/?img src =">/g,'').replace(/?>/g,'');
                var tag1 = text.firstIndexOf((/<img src="(.*?)>/g));
                var tag2 = text.lastIndexOf((/<img src="(.*?)>/g));
                var anchor1 = '<a href="images/' + res +'" data-lightbox="Christmas">';
                var anchor2 = '</a>'
                var newString = text.substring(0,tag1) + anchor1 + '<img src="' + res + '">'  + anchor2 + text.substring(tag2,text.length);
                return newString;
               
});
</script>
```

wanted output

```
I am a string and this is an image <a href="images/image.jpeg" data-lightbox="Christmas"><img=src"image.jpeg"></a>
```

I'm unsure if this is the correct way, it doesnt seem to work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, I've made some changes:

- The regex pattern needs to have `.*?` to match lazily up to the next `src` attribute or the `>` closing tag.
- The method used is String.replace, because it allows to have the full matched image `img`, and also to have the src matched group `()` in the second argument.
- Using string interpolation ``` `` ``` (backticks) eases the concatenion of the resulting string.

Look the final function:

```js
function getLightBox(text = '') {
  return text.replace(/<img.*?src="([^"]+)".*?>/g, (img, src) => {
    return `<a href="images/${src}" data-lightbox="Christmas">${img}</a>`;
  });
}

const element = document.getElementById('myElement');
element.innerHTML = getLightBox(element.innerHTML);
```

```css
img {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement">
  I am a string and this is an image:
  <img id="foo" src="image.jpeg" alt="bar">
</div>
```

You can play with the regex pattern here:

- https://regex101.com/r/79HHrn/1

Comment: Thanks! Do you know now how i could use a php variable that holds the text and use this function to transform it? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need php to do this. You can use javascript like this: `const element = document.getElementById('myTextWithImages');  element.innerHTML = getLigthBox(element.innerHTML);`

Comment: I understand that, but the whole end goal is that I have a PHP variable that i hopped to use in this javascript function and return the output back to a PHP variable. I just used a javascript example to get the javascript working

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client machine (browsers). PHP runs on the backend (server). JavaScript will only run after all PHP has been processed. Never before.

Comment: What you can do is create a PHP function that behaves exactly like this JavaScript function I've made... but you will need to ask another question because I don't know PHP to help you with that.